# How to fill empty textboxes with some value while updating database?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a form containing 6 groupboxes and 120 textboxes.  During data updation to the data base, I would like the empty textboxes to return the value "-NA-". I tried the following codes but I keep getting errors:

```
     For i As Integer = 1 To 20
        If GroupBox1.Controls("CollarTB" & i).Text = String.Empty Then
            GroupBox1.Controls("CollarTB" & i).Text = "-NA-"
        End If

        If Me.GroupBox1.Controls("CollarTB" & i).Text = String.Empty Then
            Me.Controls("CollarTB" & i).Text = "-NA-"
        End If

        If Form9.Controls(i).Text = String.Empty Then
            Form9.Controls(i).Text = "-NA-"
        End If

    Next



        If FrntTB1.Text = String.Empty Then FrntTB1.Text = "-NA-"
```

How can this be done? Any solutions please?

Also, I have another containing about 180 textboxes in a groupbox. I want to populate them all from a single row of a database at once. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `linq` to filter the `groupboxes` from the `form` and in that `groupboxes` you can filter out the `textboxes` , then simply set the values to that `textboxes` as per your requirement. try this code,

Linq Type I:

```
For Each xGroupBox As GroupBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()

    For Each xTextBox As TextBox In xGroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()

        If xTextBox.Name.StartsWith("CollarTB") andalso xTextBox.text = string.empty Then
            xTextBox.Text = "-NA-"
        End If

    Next

Next
```

Linq Type II:

```
 For Each xGroupBox As GroupBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()
     For Each xTextBox As TextBox In From xTxtbx In xGroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)() Where xTxtbx.Text.StartsWith("CollarTB") and xTxtbx.text = string.empty
         xTextBox.Text = "-NA-"
     Next
 Next
```

Non Linq version:

```
For Each xControls As Control In Me.Controls

    If TypeOf xControls Is GroupBox Then

        For Each xControls1 As Control In xControls.Controls

            If TypeOf xControls1 Is TextBox Then

                If xControls1.Name.StartsWith("CollarTB") andalso xControls1.text = string.empty  Then

                    xControls1.Text = "-NA-"

                End If

            End If

        Next

    End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks... the first Linq code worked perfectly for me... Do you by any chance have a solution for the second question?

Comment: @SaurabhSuman can you please elaborate your second question.?

Comment: I have a form in which i 6 groupboxes each having 180 textboxes. In the backend i have a MS Access database from which i have to retrieve data from a table and display it in these textboxes. Is there any short cut by which i can fill the 180 textboxes in a groupbox at once? each table has 181 fields out of which 1 field's data has already been displayed in a combobox in the groupbox. the remaining data has to be filled in the textboxes.

Comment: i have been using the following code:

`code` For i As Integer = 1 To 60
`code`            Me.Controls("L1Ob" & i).Text = objDataTable.Rows(0)("Operation" & i)
`code`        Next


....here "L1Ob"(i) are textboxes names and operation(i) is the field name...

Comment: @SaurabhSuman would you please ask this as a separate question.? because actually we had found a solution for your first problem. If we continue discussing all of our problems here, then your question will become unreadable for the future referers. By the way, asking a new question will get the attention from others rather than me. :) just intimate me while you are asking this as a separate question. :)